# Objective-C Sockets: Transfer Data

Tags: objective-c, sockets

I'm making a very simple game to gain experience in Objective-C. I found some other posts and some documentation on networking, but they all use `NSInputStream` and related classes to communicate with websites and URLs. How can I transfer data between two computers? All I really need to transfer are an X coordinate and a Y coordinate. Is there a simple way to do this? I'm new to networking.

Comment: What do you mean by "Two computers"?  Do you mean a client on which the game runs and a server or do you mean two clients on which two people are running the game?

Comment: Two clients are running the same game. One person hosts the game and the other joins. I need to transfer the X and Y of the players via some kind of socket or something similar.